# Is it possible, to edit the speech(or voice), comes from the microphone, before send it to speech recognizer?

Tags: java, android, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, equalizer

I want to equalize the speech, before it goes to speechrecognizer. I've created the new intent, which starts the speechrecognizer, and asks me to talk, and after I finish speaking it will be translated to text.
Okay, it is cool and working.

But I need to modify the voice, equalize this, before it will be translated to text. Because, I wanna give a more clear speech to the recognizer to get a better performance, a more accurate text.

Is there any possibilities, or ideas?
I appreciate any help! :))

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with speechrecignizer, but since you want to equalize the raw data from microphone then sending it to recognizer, why not using [AudioRecord](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioRecord) to do it. I've found a google-speech-api demo for you. https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/android-docs-samples/blob/master/speech/Speech/app/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/android/speech/VoiceRecorder.java. Below is the short flow:

```
final int size = mAudioRecord.read(mBuffer, 0, mBuffer.length);
// equliaze the buf you want here.
mCallback.onVoice(mBuffer, size);
```